# Issues with class instantiation after converting VS 2005 project to VS 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2005

I'm working on getting a (badly written) VB web app up to something approaching modernity by converting it off a VM running visual studio 2005 and into VS 2017.  The solution conversion went smoothly however when I try to compile it throws around 1k errors that are instantiations of user defined classes.  When I double click on any of the errors to open the code behind VS is able to determine the correct class definition and all the errors in that particular code behind will disappear from the list.  However, when I try to rerun the compilation, they're all back and the process repeats.  The instantiations and the definitions are in different projects if that matters.

My guess is there's some issue with the solution/project/references but nothing really looks glaringly wrong (there are no missing references, etc) and i'm way outside my element when it comes to dealing with legacy code this old.

I know this is kind of shot in the dark but does anyone have any thoughts on what the issue may be?  If any further info would be helpful please let me know.  I'm stumped here.

Comment: Try compiling each project individually to see if that helps identify the root of the cause

Comment: So there are 3 projects.  Two of them are kind of architecture-y in nature and the third one contains all the aspx pages.  The first two compile correctly however the third one does not. It's all the same errors repeated Type <insert class here> is not declared.

Comment: The one that does NOT compile is that the one with all the aspx pages?

Comment: Correct.  It's really strange.  Once I open a file it will clear all the errors from that file and you can follow the classes back to their declaration correctly.  And if I leave it long enough all the errors will magically disappear and I have 0 errors.  However, if I recompile or attempt to run in debug all the errors come back.  I've never seen anything like this haha

Comment: Close ALL of your (own) web pages/ controls/ modules / classes (all) windows in the IDE all of them except the ones attached to the sides, they can stay. Then recompile your projects and hopefully the error at the top is the cause.  but it is imperative you close all of them then re-compile.

Comment: Unfortunately it's nothing but that same error.  I took a screen shot as well as a kind of inner shot of the actual code block for the first 6 errors.  You can see in the inner shot  https://unsee.cc/e8f7f430/

Comment: well that's stumped me too.